# Validate name in contact form using php - $error incorrect?

Tags: php, validation, email, session

I'm having trouble validating the name in my contact form. If the name field is left empty, the form should generate an error message such as "Please enter your name". Instead there is no error message and the e-mail is allowed to be sent.  Here's my code:

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" class="form-horizontal" action="javascript:alert('success!');">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Your full name:</label>
                        <div class="controls">                    
                          <input class="span4" type="text" id="inputName" name="name" value="Your full name:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your full name:'"      onFocus="if(this.value =='Your full name:' ) this.value=''">
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </div>  
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Your email:</label>
                <div class="controls">                    
                  <input class="span4" type="text" id="inputEmail" name="email" value="Your email:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your email:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Your         email:' ) this.value=''">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPhone">Phone number:</label>
                <div class="controls">                    
                  <input class="span4" type="text" id="inputPhone" name="phone" value="Phone number:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Phone number:'"        onFocus="if(this.value =='Phone number:' ) this.value=''">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputDrums">Do you have a drum set?</label>
                <div class="controls">                    
                  <select input class="" type="text" id="inputDrums" name="drums">
                                <option>Do you have a drum set?</option>
                                <option>Yes</option>
                                <option>No</option>
                                </select>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>  

        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputLevel">What level is the student?</label>
                <div class="controls">                    
                  <select input class="span4" type="text" id="inputLevel" name="level">
                                <option>What level is the student?</option>
                                <option>Beginner</option>
                                <option>Intermediate</option>
                                <option>Advanced</option>
                                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputCity">What city do you live in?</label>
                <div class="controls">                    
                  <select input class="span4" type="text" id="inputCity" name="city">
                                <option>What city do you live in?</option>
                                <option>Boulder</option>
                                <option>Erie</option>
                                <option>Gunbarrel</option>
                                <option>Lafayette</option>
                                <option>Longmont</option>
                                <option>Louisville</option>
                                <option>Niwot</option>
                                <option>Other</option>
                                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputMessage">Message:</label>
                <div class="controls">                                        
                  <textarea class="span12" id="inputMessage" name="content" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Message:'" 
                    onFocus="if(this.value =='Message:' ) this.value=''">Message:</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="control-group captcha">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputCaptcha">Enter captcha numbers here:</label>
                <div class="controls">                    
                  <input class="" type="text" id="inputCaptcha" name="captcha" value="Enter captcha numbers here:" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter captcha numbers         here:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Enter captcha numbers here:' ) this.value=''">
                  <img src="captcha/captcha.php">
        <img src="images/trans.png" style="width: 5px; height: 5px">          

    <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Refresh captcha" style="width: 120px; height: 42px">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="submit">Send</button>
</form>

    **Contact.php**

    <?php
    /*
    Credits: Bit Repository
    URL: http://www.bitrepository.com/
    */

    include 'contact_config.php';
    session_start();
    error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    $post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

    if($post)
    {
    include 'functions.php';

    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
    $drums = stripslashes($_POST['drums']);
    $level = stripslashes($_POST['level']);
    $city = stripslashes($_POST['city']);
    $subject = "Website Inquiry";
    $message = "

    Name: ".$_POST['name']
    ."

    E-mail Address: ".$_POST['email']
    ."

    Phone: ".$_POST['phone']
    ."

    Drums: ".$_POST['drums']
    ."

    Level: ".$_POST['level']
    ."

    City: ".$_POST['city']
    ."

    Message: ".$_POST['content'];


    $error = '';

    // Check name

    if(!$name)
    {
    $error .= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
    }
    // Check email

    if(!$email)
    {
    $error .= 'Please enter an e-mail address.<br />';
    }

    if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
    {
    $error .= 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.<br />';
    }


    if(isset($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) && strtolower($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) != strtolower($_POST['captcha']))
    {
    $error .= "Incorrect captcha.<br />";
    }


    if(!$error)
    {

$mail = mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $subject, $message,
       "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
      ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
      ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

    if($mail)
    {
    echo 'OK';
    }

    }
    else
    {
    echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
    }

    }
    ?>

    **functions.php** 

        <?php
    function ValidateEmail($email)
    {

    $regex = '/([a-z0-9_.-]+)'. # name

    '@'. # at

    '([a-z0-9.-]+){2,255}'. # domain & possibly subdomains

    '.'. # period

    '([a-z]+){2,10}/i'; # domain extension 

    if($email == '') { 
return false;
    }
    else {
    $eregi = preg_replace($regex, '', $email);
    }

    return empty($eregi) ? true : false;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: have u tried echoing $name?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to do that...newbie here!  Can yo advise?  Thanks.

Comment: add  echo "hello".$name ; before if(!$name)

Comment: All that did was display "helloYour full name:" after I tried to send the e-mail.  Sorry, and I appreciate your attempt at a fix.

Comment: did u add  "Your full name:" in name input?

Comment: Tried that...didn't work.  Maybe a link to my page will help?
[link](http://inhomedrumlessons.com/contact.htm)

Comment: Found out your problem.you are sending your full name as value. Remove it as the value and pass it as the placeholder

Comment: Existing code:
    // Check name
    echo "Your full name".$name; if(!$name)
    {
    $error .= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
    }

What should I change it to?  Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question to show your html form input with the name attribute of name.

Comment: @Lenny hope my ans works for u

Comment: Added contact form in above question....any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$_POST['name']` may not be actually empty it could be something like `' '`. Replace

```
if(!$name){//...
```

with

```
if(empty($name)){//...
```

You could also trim your strings as well. e.g.

```
$name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
```

Comment: shouldnt it be if(empty($name)){

Comment: Whoops.  Good catch, fixed.

Comment: I've run the following:
`echo !''?"true":"false"; // true
 if(!'')
  echo "true";
 else
  echo "false"; // true
 var_dump(!''); // bool(true)
 $str = '';
 var_dump(!$str); // bool(true)`

Comment: `echo stripslashes('')?"true":"false"; // false` and `echo !stripslashes('')?"true":"false"; // true`, too. It may be that the form is actually sending whitespace, which doesn't evaluate to false.

Comment: What does `var_dump($error)` output if you put it just before `if(!$error){`?

Answer (score 0):

Use **isset** to verify if the parameter was sent or not

```
if(!isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $error .= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
    }
```

Try printing the $error parameter before the condition and see what the output is.

About the email varification you can use the PHP build in filters:

```
if (filter_var($email_b, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This ($email_b) email address is considered valid.";
}
```

[Example #1 Validating email addresses with filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php)

Comment: `isset()` will only work if the form didn't pass a name parameter at all.  In most cases an empty form field will pass an empty string.

Comment: Not sure what printing the $error parameter before the condition means.  Newbie here..,thanks.

Comment: Before
if (!$error)
just add echo $error     - This will help you understand what string goes into the $error variable.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, I have found that empty strings always evaluate to false, so *if the `$_POST['name']` variable is an empty string,* your code should work.

It may be, then, that you are receiving white space (e.g. a space or newline) from your form without realising it. In this case, you can filter your `$_POST` variable like so:

```
$filtered = array_map("stripslashes", array_filter(array_map("trim", $_POST)));
```

Having done this, `$filtered['name']` will not be set if `$_POST['name']` is empty or only whitespace. This can be checked with either `isset` or `array_key_exists`.

Comment: Not sure what any of that means, sorry, newbie here.  Thanks.

Comment: The [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function takes an array, calls a function on every element of the array, then returns the result as a new array, without modifying the original. The `"stripslashes"` and `"trim"` strings are used to refer to the built-in PHP functions of the same name. Finally, the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function removes elements from an array based on a test. In this case, we don't use any test, so it just removes elements that are "falsy" or fail `if()` statements, such as empty strings.

Comment: So, reading that line of code from right-to-left: we're making a new array based on `$_POST`, after `trim`ing every item, which removes whitespace from the beginning and end of the string. For strings that are only whitespace, they become empty strings, which are removed by `array_filter`. Finally, we create another new array from the `array_filter`ed array that calls `stripslashes` on every element. We store this in `$filtered` which can now be used instead of `$_POST` to get the new values.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value to placeholder

**Original code**

```
 <input class="span4" id="inputName" name="name" value="Your full name:" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Your full name:'" onfocus="if(this.value =='Your full name:' ) this.value=''" type="text">
```

To

**changed code**

```
<input class="span4" id="inputName" name="name" placeholder="your full name" type="text">
```

A place holder will appear in the input field. But When you add something to the field, the placeholder will disappear. Also when your clear text in the input field (make the input field empty) and you focus out of it, the input field will retain its placeholder value.

do this for all the input fields such as email.

But If you still want to keep the onfocus and onblur events, call this function on submit (Although I dont recommmend as this as it will only work if javascript on the client side is enabled).

```
 function()
 {
   var name = document.getElementById('inputName');
   if(name.value === "Your full name:" || name.value === "")
   {
       return false; 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Or rather use text such as 'Your full name' as a label.  But yes, remove the value attribute.

Comment: It's working now, but only partially.  The blur and focus attributes are not functioning properly now.  What did I do wrong?  Please see website contact page: [http://inhomedrumlessons.com/contact.htm

Comment: I have looked at  your code in the link and I found out that you havent changed the value to placeholder.First do that.

Comment: If you're using `onblur` and `onfocus` events are being registered client-side javascript must be enabled anyway. The only way to solve this problem while preserving those events is to use more javascript.